# Why am I getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error?

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

Hello i've built an application that will take a users input, then carry out some code dependant on the input. It all works right up until the line of code carried out within the switch case where i get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; index=53 
 it should go through the loop 6 times to build up an array of characters that are put into kc
 can anyone help?  
code:

```
    char[] k = input.toCharArray();


    char[] p =   { '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5'};


    char[] kc = { '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'};



    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i<6; i++) {


        switch (k[0]) {

            case '0':
                kc[i] = K0[p[i]]; k[0]++;
                break;

            case '1':
                kc[i] = K1[p[i]]; k[0]++;
            break;

            case '2':
                kc[i] = K2[p[i]]; k[0]++;
            break;

            case '3':
                kc[i] = K3[p[i]]; k[0]++;
            break;

            case '4':
                kc[i] = K4[p[i]]; k[0]++;
            break;

            case '5':
                kc[i] = K5[p[i]]; k[0]++;
            break;

            case '6':
                kc[i] = K6[p[i]]; k[0]++;
            break;

            case '7':
                kc[i] = K7[p[i]]; k[0]++;
            break;

            case '8':
                kc[i] = K8[p[i]]; k[0]++;
            break;

            case '9':
                kc[i] = K9[p[i]]; k[0]++;
            break;



        };

        if (k[0] == 10) {

            k[0] = 0;
        };

    }
```

Comment: What's `K0` etc? Providing the exact line and error is almost always useful.

Comment: what is `input`? show the stack trace.

Comment: 'input' comes from what the user has put into an edittext so lets say for this example the user has input 1. I will add K0 and etc now

Comment: Please note that you need not finish every block with a semicolon. If the block is closed and you put a semicolon in there it'll be only an empty statement.

Comment: Post complete stacktrace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The numeric value of a character that represents a number is not that number.  Specifically, the char `'0'` is of value `48` not `0`, `'1'` is `49` not `1`, and so on through `'9'` being `57` not `9`.  [Here's the ASCII table for reference](http://www.asciitable.com/).

You will need to convert the `char` value from `p` to a number by subtracting `48` from your `char` values.  You don't have to remember that `'0'` is `48`, just that the numeric `char` values are in order.  This means that you can simply subtract `'0'`.

Here's an example of what you'll need to change; you can make other similar changes for other cases.

```
case '0':
    kc[i] = K0[ p[i] - '0' ]; k[0]++;
    break;
```

Comment: Thank you!! makes total sense what's been happening now! very very helpful!